# Linking table entry to multiple other entries

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm attempting to create a basic music database for a school project.
I would like to link each song to three (3) other 'similar' songs.

I know how to link two tables together with `FOREIGN KEY` but I'm unsure how to link two entries within the same table.

The programs I'm using are PHPmyadmin and DBDesigner 4.

Thanks in advance for any assistance :)

Comment: You need to show us what you have done so far (code, database schema etc.).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when designing a database, you never want to "assume '(3)'." In other words, you don't want "repeating groups" such that the database design would be broken if you ever needed 4.

To me, "is-similar-to" is a *many-to-many* relationship that would list an arbitrary number of songs that are similar, with a structure such as

```
 SONG_ID_1,
 SONG_ID_2,
 DEGREE_OF_SIMILARITY   (some kind of percentage ...?)
```

So, for any song, you'd be looking to this table to find all songs that have ever been listed as "similar to" this song.  You'd incorporate this table with an `INNER JOIN`, and be prepared to deal with an *arbitrary* number of matches.

Comment: While that's a good suggestion, and something I'll have to keep in mind for future projects, what I'm attempting to do with this information is pretty basic and will only ever need three links. I'm going to (eventually, when I learn how) I'll embed the information in a webpage like this: http://puu.sh/qy7lU/cd3a1f02dc.png

Comment: A reasonable strategy, then, might be to prepare a *stored procedure* which performs this query and uses it to populate three fields in another table. Now, obviously, "it's entirely up to you" just how much "flexibility" this application wants or requires. And, it is quite commonplace for there to be "reporting tables" such as this, where "complicated queries" are performed *once* in order to provide recently-calculated summary answers "instantaneously." It's a balancing act, full of engineering tradeoffs. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a relationship table, where you keep the song id along with the linked song id.

Example:

- Table Song - ID PRIMARY KEY, NAME
- Table Song_Link - ID_SONG (from Table Song), ID_LINKED_SONG (from Table Song)

This way you can store the link between both songs on a row basis.

Take into consideration that the link goes both ways.

Comment: I'll attempt it and see how I go. Thanks!